# How can I scale down a propeller for wind tunnel testing?

Tags: propeller

I want to scale down my propeller for a wind tunnel testing. But I am unable to find any literature on it.  Please give suggestions.

Comment: Suggestions on what? How to make one smaller? Where to manufacture it? Effects of scaling?

Comment: Check out page 13 : http://teaching.ust.hk/~civl151/Course%20Notes/dimensionalAnalysis.pdf  Here is some more theory : http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node86.html

Answer (score 1):

The airfoil of the propeller should not change with size if you are scaling it up and down. As long as the airfoil is the same and the proportions are correct relative to both propellers (length, chord, pitch, etc.) that should be all you need to pay attention to.

Comment: What about the _speed_?

Comment: The speed of what?

Comment: Scaling of it. Should the flow speed in the wind tunnel be the same as that of the full-scale aircraft and the RPM of the scaled propeller the same as the full-scale one? I *don't* think so.

Comment: Wind tunnel testing of wings is done at the same speeds the wing will fly at full size. A tiny aircraft, like a BD-5 or a Cri-Cri, has to fly in the same conditions as a 747-800., A propeller is an airfoil, just like a wing. Why do you think the scaled propeller should be tested differently? There may be a reason to do so, but you haven stated it. Just curious.

Comment: I was thinking of the Reynolds number. It depends on speed, but also on the size of the structure.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. That will indeed be an issue. Unfortunately, it is beyond my level of knowledge. I did find this paper, which seems to confirm your concerns.

http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/pubs/DetersAnandaSelig-2014-AIAA-2014-2151.pdf

Comment: @JanHudec the wind tunnel results will absolutely depends on the similarity parameters. depending on the expected flight conditions, either Reynolds number or mach number will be the more important to replicate in the test